# no se visualiza icono con fontAwsome

Tags: html5, angular, font-awesome

tengo el siguiente código en mi pagina de html con angular 7

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
```

Todos los demás iconos y botones se visualizan bien mostrando trash can y otros pero el pencil no lo muestra? que puede suceder?

Comment: Que versión estas utilizando de `FontAwesome`? Ten en cuenta que Angular también tiene una versión de **FA** en el cual la llamada a los iconos es diferente

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera la version de FA es v5.7.1 y de angular 7.3.1

Comment: En ese caso la configuración para que te funcione es otra, no simplemente **referenciar el css en un tag script en el head**. Te dejo las instrucciones https://origin.fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El "pencil" definido en la versión regular (no PRO) es:

```
<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
```

https://origin.fontawesome.com/icons/pencil-alt?style=solid

Nota: `fas` y no `fa` quiere decir que este ícono se encuentra categorizado dentro del grupo `solid` de FontAwesome. Si es la versión PRO ten en cuenta además que:

- far: "regular"
- fal: "light"
- fab: "brands"

Sí, yo también extraño la simpleza de versiones anteriores a FontAwesome donde todo era `fa`.